# How do I write an HTML character without the browser converting it on Google Sites?

Tags: html, google-classic-sites

Specifically I'm trying to write `"&#773;"` with the quotation marks to indicate the character. I want the code to appear not the character.

I'm looking for alternative answers than to use `&gt;` or `&lt;` or `<pre>`.

Comment: It really depends on the context. Where are you trying to do this? Do you want the code to appear or the actual character?

Comment: ...and I'm not sure this is really on-topic for this site.

Comment: @AlEverett Where do you think would be more appropriate?

Comment: @AlEverett On Google Sites.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In HTML, the characters `<` and `>` are special (so are quotation marks in certain places). If you want these characters to appear, you'll need to encode them (as `&lt;` and `&gt;` respectively). The ampersand is used for encoding, and it follows that the ampersand is *also* a special character. If you want an actual ampersand to appear, you need to encode that too, as `&amp;`. Specifically, if you want the string `&#773;` to appear, you should encode it as `&amp;#773;`.